# HTML and BODY different backgrounds

Tags: html, css

I want to have gradient all over the HTML document, and in center of BODY tag I need another background centered.

**Edit to see how much it fails try it out:**

http://xn--wiadomesny-37b.pl/bg

This image explains it:

[image]

It fails if I put in CSS, only 1 background is displayed even, if underneath should be displayed repeat-y background:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html {
    background-color: #ffeacd;
    background-image: url(bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
body {
    background-image: url(bg_overlay.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
.content {
    width:1020px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
  <p>This content is closed in 1020px wide DIV, as to merge in most displays. </p>
  <p>Rest around is an background seen or unseen depends on users screen size. </p>
  <p>Me got 24'' so its obvious that I will see all backgrounds and even gradients as 
    blank space fillers</p>
  <p>
  <h1>See how much it fails in various browsers:</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="chrome.png">Chrome</a></li>
    <li><a href="ff.png">Firefox</a></li>
    <li><a href="ie.png">IE</a></li>
  </ul>
  </p>
  )</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Need to see your actual code.

Comment: Code provided with live example, now you can see how much it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help you:

```
html {
           background: #ffeacd url(bg.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
           width:100%;
           height:100%;
     }
body {
           background:transparent url(bg_overlay.png) center center no-repeat;
           width:100%;
           height:100%;
     }
.content {
           width:1020px;
           padding: 0px;
           margin-top: 0px;
           margin-right: auto;
           margin-bottom: 0px;
           margin-left: auto;
         }
```

Comment: It did! 2/3 done, now why IE dont use transparent PNG in background here: http://xn--wiadomesny-37b.pl/bg?

Comment: Well played  little bit with it and IE do not show graphics on HTML at all - just colour body (no img)!

Answer (score 3):

If you don’t see two backgrounds, perhaps that’s because your `body` element occupies the same area as the `html`.

The following demonstrates that the elements can have different backgrounds ( http://jsfiddle.net/ZVHqs/ ):

```
<!doctype html>
<style>
html { background: green; }
body { background: yellow; margin: 1em; }
</style>
Hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try doing this,

```
body{
    background-position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use two DIVs, one for the left side bar and one for the main content. Set the background for BODY to the gradient, and the DIV for the left side bar to whatever you want it to be.

Then you just need to focus on creating the two-column layout for the divs. [This](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) is a great primer on CSS positioning.

Comment: But it will resize my width way to much and user than will be forced to use horisontal scroll bar.

Comment: Rob - can you provide an example? :)